# C# refactoring Facade for API

Tags: c#, design-patterns, refactoring

I create a `dll` for my application. I am using `Facade design pattern` for encapsulate API who makes some programmers (not my organization) because they decision is uncomfortable.

Their API works like this:

1. Initialize object of DiadocApi
2. Auth for getting token

For initialize DiadocApi object I need `developerKey` (get for a subscription).
For authorization I need `login`, `password`.

My decision badly because it's a singleton and I need make unit-tests. That can I change in my code?

```
//I GET IT FROM NUGET PACKAGE
using Diadoc.Api;

public sealed partial class DiadocApiFacade
{
    private static readonly object _mutex = new object();

    private static DiadocApiFacade _instance;
    private string _token;
    private DiadocApi _api;

    private DiadocApiFacade() { }

    public static string DefaultUrl => "url was here";
    public string DefaultFromBoxId { get; set; }
    public DiadocApi Api { get => _api; private set => _api = value; }
    
    public static DiadocApiFacade GetInstance()
    {
        if (_instance == null)
        {
            lock (_mutex)
            {
                if (_instance == null)
                {
                    _instance = new DiadocApiFacade();
                }
            }
        }
        return _instance;
    }

    public string Authenticate(string login, string password, string privateDeveloperKey)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(login) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(password) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(developerKey))
            throw new ArgumentNullException();

        Api = new DiadocApi(developerKey, DefaultUrl, new WinApiCrypt());

        return _token = _api.Authenticate(login, password);
    }

    //method for example, >60% methods like that
    public Document GetDocument(string messageId, string documentId, string boxId = null)
    {
        return _api.GetDocument(_token, boxId ?? DefaultFromBoxId, messageId, documentId);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want to make unit tests for **your** code that's consuming `DiadocApiFacade`.

Dependency inversion to the rescue! Abstract your `DiadocApiFacade` with an interface. Make use of the **Factory Pattern** to create the object. Below is a simple example but you can expand the factory if you need the facade to behave a certain way (like a settings class to change where it's connecting to).

`GetOrCreate` Will return the same instance but if you're using a dependency [injection framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/dependency-injection) in your project (there are many that might suite your needs), use that instead.

```cs
public interface IDiadocApiFacade
{
    string Authenticate(string login, string password, string privateDeveloperKey);
    public Document GetDocument(string messageId, string documentId, string boxId);
    public Document GetDocument(string messageId, string documentId);

}

public class DiadocApiFacadeFactory
{
    private static IDiadocApiFacade? _instance = null;

    public IDiadocApiFacade Create() //Add parameters 
    {
        return new DiadocApiFacade();
    }

    public IDiadocApiFacade GetOrCreate()
    {
        if(_instance == null)
            _instance = Create();

        return _instance;
    }
}

public sealed partial class DiadocApiFacade : IDiadocApiFacade
{
    internal DiadocApiFacade() { }

    public string Authenticate(string login, string password, string privateDeveloperKey) => string.Empty;
    

    public Document GetDocument(string messageId, string documentId)
        => GetDocument(messageId, documentId, null);

    public Document GetDocument(string messageId, string documentId, string? boxId) => new Document();
    
}
```

Then you can just make use of [moq)[https://www.nuget.org/packages/moq/] for your unit testing and fake the implementation of `IDiadocApiFacade`

Comment: If I need parameters in method `Create`, I will have to add params into `GetOrCreate`?

Comment: Yea cause that will pass them to `Create`. `GetOrCreate` is just a simple shortcut for you to access the same instance. If you can inject `IDiadocApiFacade` into you DI layer, that's preferred.